WireGuard wizardry to bypass CGNAT with a VPS?
I know people probably have asked about this before, but I'm trying to implement something specific for over a month and haven't completely succeeded. I have a bunch of stuff on my home network which I use almost constantly. For remote access, I stopped forwarding individual ports for services after I learned that it wasn't a good idea security-wise and also a pain to manage. Instead, I opted for configuring an OpenVPN server on an old PC running Ubuntu and just have that individual port forwarded in my router.
Then, I got put behind CGNAT and the people I talked to over at my ISP don't even seem to know what that is... But in any case, there's nothing I can do about that, so I looked some solutions. I found out about Tailscale, which is quite easy to set up, but I really didn't like the fact you have to install a client app and log in for every single device, and for some reason the bandwidth seems to be limited. Then I found out WireGuard was a thing, and supposedly faster and easier to set up than OpenVPN, so I gave it a shot.
I finally decided to shell out and get a VPS from IONOS for the sole purpose of getting a public IPv4 address to my name. I installed WireGuard on both my home server and the VPS and set up a tunnel, which surprisingly worked. The VPS is quite far away, so it adds some latency, but I guess there's nothing to do about that.
Then I wanted to make client configs for my laptop, phone and other devices, which would connect to the VPS, and then use the existing tunnel to reach my home network and access local services. The thing is, though, that the first time I did this all traffic ended up going through the VPS, effectively using it as a VPN, and this would slow everything down unnecessarily. I wanted to keep this functionality as it would occasionally come in useful, but also add two other types of clients which would a) only act as an overlay network to access my home network but leave other traffic alone or b) use my home server as an exit node, Tailscale-style.
So far I haven't managed to get this to work. It's probably some dumb obvious thing (it always seems to be with these things) but I'm at a loss as to what it is. I even tried asking ChatGPT and the "solutions" it suggested not only didn't fix the issue but broke a bunch of other stuff it took me a while to fix. I really am in over my head with all these networking things (iptables, config files, firewall rules? it never ends...) and would really appreciate any help. I think the core idea makes sense, but I would also be open to any other approaches. And I'm sure this could be useful to other people stuck with CGNATing ISPs.
Here's a copy of the config files, maybe there's something there I'm missing? And I already enabled IPv4 forwarding in/etc/sysctl.conf.
    ## VPS ##
    [Interface]
    Address = 10.0.0.1/24
    ListenPort = 51820
    PrivateKey = <key>
    MTU = 1420
    # Enable IP forwarding and NAT
    PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens6 -j MASQUERADE
    PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens6 -j MASQUERADE
    # Home Server Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32, 192.168.0.0/24
    PersistentKeepalive = 25
    # Client 1 (overlay) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
    # Client 2 (overlay) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32
    # Client 3 (overlay) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.5/32
    # Client 4 (overlay) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32
    # Client 5 (overlay) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.7/32
    # Client 6 (vps_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.8/32
    # Client 7 (vps_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.9/32
    # Client 8 (vps_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.10/32
    # Client 9 (vps_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.11/32
    # Client 10 (vps_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.12/32
    # Client 11 (home_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.13/32
    # Client 12 (home_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.14/32
    # Client 13 (home_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.15/32
    # Client 14 (home_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.16/32
    # Client 15 (home_exit) Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.17/32
    
    ## HOME ##
    [Interface]
    Address = 10.0.0.2/24
    PrivateKey = <key>
    # Enable forwarding for local network (192.168.0.0/24)
    PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eno1 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
    PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o eno1 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
    # VPS Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    Endpoint = mydomain.com:51820
    AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
    PersistentKeepalive = 25
    # Client 11 Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.13/32
    # Client 12 Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.14/32
    # Client 13 Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.15/32
    # Client 14 Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.16/32
    # Client 15 Peer
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.17/32
    
    ## CLIENT 11 HOME EXIT ##
    [Interface]
    Address = 10.0.0.13/24
    PrivateKey = <key>
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    Endpoint = mydomain.com:51820
    AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, 10.0.0.2/32
    
    ## CLIENT 6 VPS EXIT##
    [Interface]
    Address = 10.0.0.8/24  
    PrivateKey = <key>
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    Endpoint = mydomain.com:51820
    AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
    
    ## CLIENT 1 OVERLAY ##
    [Interface]
    Address = 10.0.0.3/24
    PrivateKey = <key>
    [Peer]
    PublicKey = <key>
    Endpoint = mydomain.com:51820
    AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.0/24


The problem is not specific to WireGuard, it would happen with any VPN, and it was answered for OpenVPN (and the solution will be the same). You need to route replies back via tunnel rather than directly. To do this, you have to set up "split access", and how to do that depends heavily on the system to be accessed. For Linux, LARTC is your guide, and here I explained it. Also notice, that this question was migrated to SuperUser, because home labs are off topic on ServerFault.
